# Apply american fuzzy lop as a part of Travis CI?

Tags: travis-ci, american-fuzzy-lop

I would like to run [american fuzzy lop](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/) as a part of Travis CI run. How can I do that?

Comment: Here is the quickstart guide in case it helps answering the question: http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/QuickStartGuide.txt - with `AFL_EXIT_WHEN_DONE=1` exported, afl runs can be automated.

Comment: What about Travis CI time limits? AFL execution can take a lot of time...

Comment: There's no way around that, which is why you need a different model: either add a timeout using `timeout` command or push the AFL output directory to your repo and see if any changes happened. You can also replace `cycles_wo_finds > 20` from 20 to a smaller number here: https://github.com/d33tah/afl-fuzz-releases/blob/ec7f52279fabf39d9a44dd9a256bf5a4cafafe9c/afl-fuzz.c#L3701

Answer (score 2):

Here are my attempts - I managed to run AFL this way:

https://github.com/d33tah/travis-test-c-app

*.travis.yml*

```
language: c
install: wget "http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/releases/afl-1.88b.tgz" -O- | tar zxf - ; pushd . ; cd afl-*; make PREFIX=/tmp/afl install; echo core | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern; popd
```

*Makefile*

```
CC=/tmp/afl/bin/afl-gcc
all: app
test: app
    ./perform_fuzzing
```

*perform_fuzzing*

```
#!/bin/bash
AFL_EXIT_WHEN_DONE=1 /tmp/afl/bin/afl-fuzz -i i -o o ./app >/dev/null
cat o/fuzzer_stats
```

*configure*

```
#!/bin/sh
true
```

*app.c*

```
int main() {
    if (getchar() == '1')
        abort();
    return 0;
}
```

## Note:

As user [cubuspl42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1483676/cubuspl42) pointed out in his comment to this question, Travis CI has time limitations though. This means that you might want to push the output directory to Git and run AFL in resume mode instead. You might also want to wrap the command with [`timeout`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) program and/or replace `cycles_wo_finds > 20` with a smaller number in [this line](https://github.com/d33tah/afl-fuzz-releases/blob/ec7f52279fabf39d9a44dd9a256bf5a4cafafe9c/afl-fuzz.c#L3701) (and possibly some others in the future).